# how to restore Webview State when swiping from view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I have 3 fragments with `WebView`.

I'm using those three with `ViewPager` and `Tablayout`.

The Problem is whenever I'm swiping from 1st page to 3rd page and then going back to first page it's reloading and vice versa.

How do I preserve the state of `Webview` in `Tablayout` which has three or four pages.

Comment: I'm simply loading **Google.com** to webview in a fragment. And adding that single fragment three times in a **FragmentPagerAdapter** to setup with ViewPager. The thing is _1st fragment is loaded and i'm swiping to 3rd fragment then again swiping back to 1st fragment but it's reloading that page_. is there any another way to save the state of WebView?

Comment: @reporter do you have any idea to preserve the state of webview to resume multiple times after loading one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, ViewPager destroys previous Fragments. You can change it using the following line -

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(CUSTOM_NUMBER);
```